# Visual Studio Code - Disable autocomplete "<>"

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm working on a `.html.erb` file and when I type `<` character, VSCode autocompletes with `>`.
I'm looking to disable this functionality specifically for the `<` character.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why? Every `<` needs to be matched with a `>`. If you want a literal `<` in the text use `&lt;`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following options inside your **settings.json** file:

```json
"emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": false,
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never",
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"html.format.enable": false,
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "preserve"
```

Consider modifying these to fit your needs.